# End as keyword in Oracle SQL Case statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-ucm, idoc

I use two cases in below query to get results of daction & ApprovalType.
While running the below query in Oracle SQL creates two new temp columns as daction_1 & ApprovalType _1 for daction & ApprovalType columns respectively. Now, i want to use these keywords in my IDOC code but since temp columns are created I'm not able to use them. How to resolve this?

```
SELECT WH.dActionDate,
  WH.xWF_SendTo,
  WH.dAction,
  ATY.ApprovalType,
  WH.xWorkflowComments,
  CASE
    WHEN NVL(ApprovalType,'') IS NULL
    THEN xPurposeForRejection
    ELSE ApprovalType
  END AS ApprovalType,
  CASE
    WHEN NVL(dAction,'')      ='SendTo'
    AND NVL(ApprovalType,'') IS NOT NULL
    OR NVL(dAction,'')        ='Approve'
    THEN 'Approve'
    ELSE 'Reject'
  END AS dAction
FROM WorkflowHistory WH,
  Reason Re,
  ApprovalType ATY
WHERE UPPER(dDocName)     = UPPER('D_1239178')
AND xPurposeForSubmission = Re.ReasonID(+)
AND xDocApproval          = ATY.ApprovalTypeID(+)
AND (dAction             IN('Reject','Approve')
OR (dAction               ='SendTo'
AND ApprovalType         IS NOT NULL))
AND ROWNUM               <= 5
ORDER BY dActionDate DESC,
  dActionMillis
```

Comment: First, what does `IDOC` stand for?  Second, you've tagged this for MySQL and Oracle.  Which of the two are you really using?  Third, why are you aliasing your `CASE` statements to use an alias that matches a column that you're already selecting?  Why wouldn't you choose a unique alias that allows you to differentiate the two?

Comment: In Oracle, an empty string is treated as Null, so Nvl(dAction,'') is the same as dAction

Answer (score 0):

Looking at column names I assume that `Idoc` is script language used in Oracle Webcenter Content Server (formerly Oracle UCM). I don't have a running instance on-hand to check, but I am pretty sure that you can create database view with columns you need and then see it as regular table in Configuration Manager. [Following link](http://jonathanhult.com/blog/2013/11/use-database-view-webcenter-content-schema-view/) provides some details of configuration process. The other option is to move your logic to Idoc code itself although it may be less performant.

Comment: Friends, thanks. I'm working on Oracle. IDOC is just another progr. language. Main issue is how can i use daction or ApprovalType variable in any other programming language